# Subfigure plot in conflict with psfragfig

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subfloats, psfrag

I am trying to place 2 graphs one next to the other using pstools. I have generated 2 graphs using the commands

```
hFig = figure(1);
set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto')
set(hFig, 'Position', [0 0 300 200])
plot(rand(2))
xlabel('$k$')
ylabel('$t$')
matlabfrag('C:/Users/5xum/Dropbox/Magisterij/slike/test1')
```

and of course

```
hFig = figure(1);
set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto')
set(hFig, 'Position', [0 0 300 200])
plot(rand(2))
xlabel('$k$')
ylabel('$t$')
matlabfrag('C:/Users/5xum/Dropbox/Magisterij/slike/test2')
```

I now try to create a nice latex file using pdflatex and the file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[width=\textwidth]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \psfragfig{test1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \psfragfig{test2}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But the result is that the pictures overlap and are too far to the right.
I have tried different crop styles and different subfigure widths, but nothing changes a darn thing. I will appreciate any help offered.

Thank you.

Comment: This is probably a bounding box problem. Use `\fbox{\psfragfig{..}}` to see what the bounding box looks like and include a link to an image of the output. Also, if you're using PS-related image, you should compile with `latex`, not `pdflatex`. These file formats are not interchangeable, unless you convert them. [`epstopdf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf) can help in that regard.

Comment: Running latex produces exactly the same output as using pdflatex. However I have just noticed that the example I provided is not good, as in it the pictures actually span the whole width of the text. In my work, they are shifted to the right.

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/127225/edit) and add the appropriate details. You mention that "the example [you] provided is not good". Also add links to images. Someone with edit privileges will re-embed them so things are more clear.

Comment: Will do so when I will be able to reproduce the error I wish to remove... Sorry, I'm working on it...